# Problema com JPQL utilizando JSF

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Estou seguindo um livro Java EE 7 com JSF, PrimeFaces e CDI por Thiago Farias.

No meu persistence.xml, seguindo o livro, tenho apenas a definição do meu datasource, segue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                           xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="GescorpPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
    <properties> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/gescorpbd" /> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" /> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" /> 
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" /> 
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
    </properties> 
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Entidade Lancamento:

```
package br.com.freela.gescorp.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "lancamento")
    public class Lancamento implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Long id;
        private Pessoa pessoa;
        private String descricao;
        private BigDecimal valor;
        private TipoLancamento tipo;
        private Date dataVencimento;
        private Date dataPagamento;

        // ...
    }
```

Método que faz a consulta ao banco:

```
public List<Lancamento> todos(){
    TypedQuery<Lancamento> query = manager.createQuery("from Lancamento", Lancamento.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Exception:

```
 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Lancamento is not mapped [from Lancamento]
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(UIViewAction.java:562)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:654)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Lancamento is not mapped [from Lancamento]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:350)
        at br.com.freela.gescorp.repository.Lancamentos.todos(Lancamentos.java:22)
        at br.com.freela.gescorp.controller.ConsultaLancamentosBean.consultar(ConsultaLancamentosBean.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Luiz, pelo log da exceção "Lancamento is not mapped", parece que você esqueceu de declarar a tua entidade no persistence.xml.

Comment: Como está sua entidade `Lancamento`? Está anotada como `@Entity`? Outra coisa: dependendo do caso você não é precisa declarar cada entidade no `persistence.xml` se tanto o XML quanto a(s) entidade(s) estão no mesmo `classes` `classpath`. Inclua mais informações sobre seu projeto.

Comment: Bom vamos lá, minha entidade `Lancamento` já está anotada.Vou editar minha pergunta..

Comment: Pessoal editei a pergunta com mais informações, como sei que o meu persistence está no mesmo classpath das entidades?

Comment: Pessoal resolvi colocando os `<class>` no `persistence.xml` mas gostaria de saber como faço para não precisar fazer estes mapeamentos. Assim com o @Bruno César informou, incluindo no mesmo `classpath`. Att.

Comment: O 'mesmo classpath' seria ter as classes anotadas e o persistence,xml dentro do mesmo src. Por que em alguns casos, as classes anotadas poderiam estar em um .jar, nesse caso, não estariam dentro do src.

Answer (score 0):

o mapeamento está correto, sendo assim deve estar faltando a definição da class no `persistence.xml`, uma outra alternativa, é ativar a detecção automática, onde o JPA irá buscar as classes do projeto anotadas com `@Entity`, para fazê-lo, basta incluir a property `<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />` como você pode ver no exemplo abaixo:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" /> 
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
</properties>
```